# Arithmetic functions proof

Tags: number-theory

Theorem: Let $f$ be an arithmetic function such that $f(1)=1$. Then there exists a unique arithmetic function $g$ such that $f\ast g =\epsilon$. The arithmetic function $g$ is called the Dirichlet inverse of $f$.

I am looking for the proof of the following Corollary

Let $f$ and $h$ be arithmetic functions such that $f(1)=h(1)=1$. Then, there exists a unique arithmetic function $g$ such that $f\ast g=h$.

Note: the arithmetic function $\epsilon$ is defined by:

$$
\epsilon(n) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }n=1\\
0, & \text{if }n>1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: If this is a corollary, it should be a straightforward consequence of some other result. But if you don't tell us what this result is, we cannot help you.

Comment: This is a result of the theorem related with the Dirichlet inverse. I will edit my question and add this theorem.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted, P.D.?

Comment: I think that it is a good answer! Does the last part show the uniqueness of that function?

Comment: If you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you must include @Gerry in it somewhere. Yes, it shows uniqueness: it shows that if $k$ and $m$ are solutions, then $k=m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $fg=e$. Let $k=gh$. Then $$fk=f(gh)=(fg)h=eh=h$$ Moreover, if $fm=h$, then $fgm=gh=k$, but also $fgm=em=m$, so $m=k$.